# How to trace references in an asynchronous IO code in WinDBG?

Tags: asynchronous, windbg

I have the addresses of two SqlConnection objects and wish to understand who holds a reference to them.

**Object 1**

```
0:042> !mroot 000000b97fd45868
AppDomain 000000bdeb50b7a0: GCHandle(Pinned) @ 000000bdebc61bf8
000000bd7796f6d8[System.Object[]]
000000b97fd46308[a8iDynamixV30.BL.GlobalSetting]
000000b97fd45b18[a8i.a8iDatabaseConnection]
000000b97fd45868[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]
```

**Object 2**

```
0:042> !mroot 000000b99a5b0cf0
CLR Thread 0x57 @ R14
000000bb92887ac8[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000bb928d8048[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000bb928d7ff8[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000b9996a5ff0[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000b9996a5fa0[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000b9996a92a8[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000b9996a9258[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000bb928f0dc8[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000bb928f0d78[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000ba8ea86a18[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000ba8ea869c8[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000bb929084f8[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000bb929084a8[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000bb9291c4f8[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000bb9291c4a8[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000ba8eaa5dc8[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000ba8eaa5c78[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000bc99588ce8[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000bc99588c98[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000ba8eaddd60[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000ba8eaddc10[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000bc9c734110[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000bc9c7340c0[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000bc9c735330[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000bc9c7351e0[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000ba8eb1d158[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000ba8eb1d108[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000b999769f38[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000b999769de8[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000bb9298df28[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000bb9298ded8[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000b99a5c5980[System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation]
000000b99a5c5930[System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask]
000000b99a5c58f0[System.Action`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.Task, mscorlib]]]
000000b99a5c58d0[System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper+c__DisplayClass22_0]
000000b99a5c5890[System.Action]
000000b99a5c5870[System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext+c__DisplayClass22_0]
000000b99a5be490[System.Action]
000000b99a5be470[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner]
000000b99a5bed30[SharpTop.Common.Utils.SqlUtil+d__1e`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]]
000000b99a5b0cf0[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]
```

I can pretty much understand what is going on with the Object 1, yet I am totally confused about the Object 2. I understand that the Object 2 is part of an async I/O, but is it at all possible to trace it back to the owner?

If not, can the code be written in a way that while being asynchronous it is also friendly to postmortem debugging?

Comment: You know neither for object 1 nor for object 2 who "owns" it. The owner of virtual memory is a process. If you want to know which line of code created the object, you need a profiler (something like UMDH but for .NET)

Comment: Hmm, but I can reason about the root chain of Object 1. I can cross reference it with the source code and reach meaningful conclusions. Nothing of the kind is possible with the Object 2.